# Looping through DataFrame with previous/next values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iteration

I have following DataFrame df, where `user` and `status` are already sorted in ascending order:

```
user  count  status

A     1      completed
A     2      not completed
B     1      not completed
B     2      completed
B     3      not completed
C     1      completed
C     2      not completed
C     3      completed
D     1      not completed
D     2      completed
D     3      not completed
D     4      completed
```

I need to tag each the two rows where one `user`'s status `not completed` is followed by `completed`. Hence, the logic should be along the lines:

```
for each user:
  set rows where "not completed" comes before "completed" == 1
  set rows where "completed" comes after "not completed" == 1
```

Here's the desired result:

```
user  count  status           selection

A     1      completed        0
A     2      not completed    0
B     1      not completed    1
B     2      completed        1
B     3      not completed    0
C     1      completed        0
C     2      not completed    1
C     3      completed        1
D     1      not completed    1
D     2      completed        1
D     3      not completed    1
D     4      completed        1
```

I'd prefer a solution with **iterrows() or itertuples()**, but ran into issues tagging both lines, and to select the previous/next index. Would be great to see potential solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A bit verbose but you can `groupby` and `transform` with `np.select`:

```
def func(d):
    s = np.select([(d.eq("not completed") & d.shift(-1).eq("completed")),
                   (d.eq("completed") & d.shift().eq("not completed"))],
                  [1, 1], 0)
    return s

df["new"] = df.groupby("user")["status"].transform(func)

print (df)

   user  count         status  new
0     A      1      completed    0
1     A      2  not completed    0
2     B      1  not completed    1
3     B      2      completed    1
4     B      3  not completed    0
5     C      1      completed    0
6     C      2  not completed    1
7     C      3      completed    1
8     D      1  not completed    1
9     D      2      completed    1
10    D      3  not completed    1
11    D      4      completed    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) & [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) on column `status`.

On each row, check `status` either:

```
current row "not completed" comes before "completed"
```

by `g.eq('not completed') & g.shift(-1).eq('completed')`  [`.shift(-1)` to get the contents of next row]

or:
current row "completed" comes after "not completed"`

by `g.eq('completed') & g.shift(1).eq('not completed')`   [`.shift(1)` to get the contents of previous row]

, as follows:

```
df['selection'] = (df.groupby('user')['status']
                    .apply(lambda g: 
                               g.eq('not completed') & g.shift(-1).eq('completed') |
                               g.eq('completed') & g.shift(1).eq('not completed')
                          ).astype(int)
                  )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   user  count         status  selection
0     A      1      completed          0
1     A      2  not completed          0
2     B      1  not completed          1
3     B      2      completed          1
4     B      3  not completed          0
5     C      1      completed          0
6     C      2  not completed          1
7     C      3      completed          1
8     D      1  not completed          1
9     D      2      completed          1
10    D      3  not completed          1
11    D      4      completed          1
```